# Serverless offline complains about missing stack before the first deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

I am trying to run locally a serverless application, but it is throwing this error:

```sh
Stack with id <my_stack_id> does not exist
```

I didn't deploy the stack yet, just trying to run it locally. It is possible that the offline serverless plugin only works with an existing deployed stack?

Comment: Hello, offline should work without prior deployments. Could you please share a bit more about your current setup?

Comment: "Serverless offline"... while the question looks well, I think the common terminology for the cloud computing still needs some improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to deploy your stack

Things you need to have to use serverless offline :

```yaml
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
```

in your serverless.yml file

then run the command `sls offline start`

then you can call your lambda functions with `sls invoke local`